# Не изменяется background-color после F5

Tags: javascript

В целом, проблема такая. Есть `div`, внутри которого можно изменять цвета для этого `div` через `selector/radio`. Значения фона (`background-color`) передаются на сервер в БД. Цвета меняются хорошо, но до перезагрузки страницы, т.е. после нажатия F5, `background-color` в `div` не меняется. После рефреша, `background-color` остаётся всегда тот, который был последним до рефреша. Но, на сервер, отправляется корректное значение, которое выбрал пользователь.

Проблема где-то в этом куске, видимо.

```
     ....
    var selectorCache = {};

        function selectElement(htmlId) {
            if (htmlId in selectorCache) {
                console.log('selectorCache');
                console.log(selectorCache[htmlId]);
                return selectorCache[htmlId];
            }
            var $field = $('#' + htmlId);
            selectorCache[htmlId] = $field;
            return $field;
        }
...
setValue: function (htmlId, value) {
          $field=selectElement(htmlId);
          var $child = $field.children();
          $child.remove();
          $field.css({'background-color': value.value});}
```

Почему считаю что в нём, а потому что, если вместо `$field=selectElement(htmlId)` использовать даже вот так `$field=document.getElementById('htmlId');`, то всё работает нормально. Если у кого-то есть идеи по этой проблеме, просьба поделиться решением.

P.S Первоначальные данные "прилетают" с сервера, то есть, каким цветом должен быть фон. По этой причине, фон и устанавливается тот, который был последним до перезапуска страницы.

Также, заметил то, что для `$field` атрибут `isConnected`, как я понимаю, это [Node isConnected()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/isConnected) до перезапуска страницы = `true`, после перезапуска он `false`, но только если смотреть через дебаггер. Если вызывать через `document.getElementById('htmlId').isConnected`, то он всегда возвращает `true`.

Comment: банально но ctrl+f5  пробните может кэш

Comment: К сожалению, не всё так просто. Через web-tools ставил Disable cache/Enable cache. Не помогало. Открывал инкогнито. Другой браузер...